# IQueryable<T> extension method for advanced where

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I'm trying to add extension method for `IQueryable<T>` in order to attach specific where to `IQueryable`.

Assuming user is searching for data with name equal to `"Matt"`

```
public IEnumerable<Employees> Search(String name)
{
    var qList = _context.Employees;
    if(!String.isNullOrEmpty(name))
        qList = qList.Where(emp => emp.Name == name);
    return qList.ToList();
}
```

Now if user is searching for data with name that starts with `"Matt"` - He will probably try to write something like `"Matt%**"` or `"Matt*"` in a specific textbox. to predict this I can do:

```
public IEnumerable<Employees> Search(String name)
{
    var qList = _context.Employees;
    if(!String.isNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        string extractedName = name.Replace("%","").Replace("*","");
        if(name.EndsWith("%") || name.EndsWith("*");
            qList = qList.Where(emp => emp.Name.StartsWith(extractedName));
    }

    return qList.ToList();
}
```

A lot of IF statements will be here to predict all of possibilities but OK. I can do that. but what I don't like is to repeat my code every time I do such feature.

How can i make extension method for

```
IQueryable<T>
```

which will do this checks all the time for me?

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyAdvancedSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> qList, String searchText)
{
    if(!String.isNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    /// ... Problem starts here.. because I cannot make this "Where": 
    qList.Where(prop=>prop.??? == searchText);
    /// ... I dont know how to tell my method which field should be filtered
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've managed to create a extension method which looks OK:

```
        public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> qList, Func<T,string> property, string text )
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                if ((text.StartsWith("%") || text.StartsWith("*")) && (text.EndsWith("*") || text.EndsWith("*")))
                    qList = qList.Where(e => property(e).Contains(text));

                else if (text.StartsWith("%") || text.StartsWith("*"))
                    qList = qList.Where(e => property(e).EndsWith(text));

                else if (text.EndsWith("%") || text.EndsWith("*"))
                    qList = qList.Where(e => property(e).StartsWith(text));
                else
                    qList = qList.Where(e => property(e) == text);
            }
            return qList;
        }
```

but when I try to do qList.Tolist() I'm receiving error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>()
.Where(o => Invoke(__property_0, o)
== __text_1)' could not be translated.

InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>() .Where(o => Invoke(__property_0, o) == __text_1)' 
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Contains will also be in method... if user writes something like %Matt%, but Contains is invalid for value Matt%... this should be startsWith..

Comment: because they sometimes want to search for table with field Name that StartsWith Matt.. and sometimes is exactly Matt.... it's just an example..  this can be a product number like C000211B... and you are searching for all products ending with 11B.. or starting with C0.. or contains 211. This is why you will use % or *

Comment: bit short of time so I can't fully flesh this out as an answer. You probably want your new extension method to have another argument, propSelector or something like that which would be of type `Func<T,string>` you could then use this func in your where to get the value you want to compare `qList.Where(x => propSelector(x) == searchText);` . you'd then call it `context.Employees.MyAdvancedSearch("Mark", (x) => x.Name);`

Comment: yes Dave.. this is exactly what i need.. but i dont know how to do it :)

Comment: @rychu151 I've given you 90% of what you need in that comment. Try have a search around for C# delegates, C# anonymous methods, C# Func  that should you help you get to grips with whats going on

Comment: do there is any change to fix this: ```InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>()
.Where(o => Invoke(__property_0, o)
== __text_1)' could not be translated.```

Comment: You'll need an expression, not a func.

Comment: Don't spoil your users. Make them use one wildcard character, `*` preferably, because that's almost ubiquitous. Then replace it by `%` and use the `Like` method your ORM offers.

Comment: Hi rychu151. Including an answer to a question as part of the question is against the StackOverflow etiquette. I would suggest to remove the answer from the question, and post it as [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyAdvancedSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> qList, Expression<Func<T, string>> property, String text)
{
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null;

    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(property);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
    var right = Expression.Constant(text, typeof(string));
    Expression body = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        if ((text.StartsWith("%") || text.StartsWith("*")) && (text.EndsWith("%") || text.EndsWith("*")))
            body = Expression.Call(left, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(text, typeof(string)));

        else if (text.StartsWith("%") || text.StartsWith("*"))
                body = Expression.Call(left, "EndsWith", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(text, typeof(string)));

        else if (text.EndsWith("%") || text.EndsWith("*"))
                body = Expression.Call(left, "StartsWith", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(text, typeof(string)));
        else
                body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, right);
    }

    expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

    qList = qList.Where(expression);
        return qList;
}
public static string GetPropertyName<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> property)
{
    MemberExpression member = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    PropertyInfo info = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

    return info.Name;
}
```

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyAdvancedSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> qList, Func<T, string> func, String searchText)
        {
            qList.Where(prop => func(prop) == searchText);

            return qList;
        }
```


Then you can call it like this:

```
var qList = _context.Employees.MyAdvancedSearch((emp) => emp.Name, extractedname)
```

Comment: Looks fine but now it throws me an error:
```InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Employee>()
.Where(o => Invoke(__property_0, o)
== __text_1)' could not be translated.```

Comment: I just tried this and it works on my side. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: Even if it "works" on your version of EF, it still won't be performed at the db but rather in memory since there's not an expression tree here to deconstruct

Answer (score 4):

The above answers using a `Func<>` won't work because Entity Framework (or any ORMs) cannot decompose a delegate into its constituent parts in order to convert it to SQL. `IQueryable<>` is designed around the `Expression` API, which means you would need to replace the `Func<,>` with an `Expression<,>`.

However, you cannot simply invoke an `Expression` like you would a delegate so switching the type can't/won't fix solve this alone. Instead, you could **rewrite** the expression using a helper method and an `ExpressionVisitor` that translates your logic into a form that Entity Framework *can* deconstruct and convert to SQL. Our helper method will take two parameters:

- the `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>` representing the property in question, and
- an `Expression<TProperty, bool>` representing the filtering clause.

(`TProperty` in our case will resolve to `string`)

We'll create a new `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` by replacing references to the `TProperty` (`string`) parameter of the second (filtering) expression with the *body* of the first (property) expression:

```cs
public static class QueryExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> qList, 
        Expression<Func<T, string>> property, 
        string text)
    {
        
        var filterText = text?.Trim('%', '*');
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterText))
            return qList;

        var matchEnd = text.StartsWith("*") || text.StartsWith("%");
        var matchStart = text.EndsWith("*") || text.EndsWith("%");
            
        if (matchEnd && matchStart)
            return qList.Where( TranslateFilter( property, e => e.Contains( filterText ) ) );
    
        if (matchEnd)
            return qList.Where( TranslateFilter( property, e => e.EndsWith( filterText ) ) );
            
        if (matchStart)
            return qList.Where( TranslateFilter( property, e => e.StartsWith( filterText ) ) );
            
        return qList.Where( TranslateFilter( property, e => e == text ) );
    }
    
    private static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> TranslateFilter<TEntity, TProperty>( 
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> prop, 
        Expression<Func<TProperty, bool>> filter)
    {
        var newFilterExpression = new Visitor<TEntity>(prop).Visit(filter);
        return (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) newFilterExpression;
    }
    
    private class Visitor<TEntity> : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;
        private readonly Expression _body;
        public Visitor(LambdaExpression prop)
        {
            _parameter = prop.Parameters[0];
            _body = prop.Body;
        }
    
        // return the body of the property expression any time we encounter
        // the parameter expression of the filter expression
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => _body;

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            if (node is LambdaExpression lamda)
            {
                // Visit the body of the filter lambda, replacing references to the string 
                // parameter with the body of the property expression
                var newBody = this.Visit(lamda.Body);
                
                // construct a new lambda expression with the new body and the original parameter
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newBody, _parameter);
            }            
            return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Unlike the answer above, this will work with any "special" functions that are supported by Entity Framework--no need to manually write starts/ends with, etc. logic that builds of Expressions piecemeal.

Though we've limited it to `string` via the extension method, the above could be used with properties of any type, for example `int`. The following is an example that would let you accept textual filters such as `>= 5` or `!= 33` against an integral column:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> FilterNumber<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> qList, 
    Expression<Func<T, int>> property, 
    string filterQuery)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterQuery))
        return qList;

    var match = Regex.Match(filterQuery.Trim(), "^(?<sym><=|<|>|>=|={1,2}|!=|<>)?\\s?(?<num>\\d+)$");
    if (!match.Success)
        throw new Exception();

    var number = int.Parse(match.Groups["num"].Value);
    
    // no symbol, assume exact match
    if (!match.Groups["sym"].Success)
        return qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c == number));

    return match.Groups["sym"].Value switch
    {
        "==" => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c == number)),
        "="  => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c == number)),
        "!=" => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c != number)),
        "<>" => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c != number)),
        "<"  => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c <  number)),
        "<=" => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c <= number)),
        ">"  => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c >  number)),
        _    => qList.Where(TranslateFilter(property, c => c >= number))
    };
}
```

Comment: Just posted an update on my answer. It works now

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like you are using Entity Framework, so the LINQ statement is trying to create a SQL query for you under the covers. But it is not able to create a SQL statement from the 'property(e)' function invocation. You could first cast your IQueryable to a list to extract the data into memory. LINQ will then stop trying to convert the query to SQL. Not sure about the performance implications of doing that though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally version that worked for me:

```
public static IQueryable<T> MyAdvancedSearch<T>(this IQueryable<T> qList, Expression<Func<T, string>> property, String searchExpression)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchExpression))
                return qList;
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null;

            var propertyName = GetPropertyName(property);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var left = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate((Expression)parameter, Expression.Property);
            var right = Expression.Constant(searchExpression, typeof(string));

            var pattern = new Regex("[*%]"); 
            string searchText = pattern.Replace(searchExpression, "");
            Expression body = null;
    
                if ((searchExpression.StartsWith("%") || searchExpression.StartsWith("*")) && (searchExpression.EndsWith("*") || searchExpression.EndsWith("*")))
                    body = Expression.Call(left, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(searchText, typeof(string)));

                else if (searchExpression.StartsWith("%") || searchExpression.StartsWith("*"))
                    body = Expression.Call(left, "EndsWith", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(searchText, typeof(string)));

                else if (searchExpression.EndsWith("%") || searchExpression.EndsWith("*"))
                    body = Expression.Call(left, "StartsWith", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(searchText, typeof(string)));
                else
                    body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, right);
          

            expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);

            qList = qList.Where(expression);
            return qList;
        }
        public static string GetPropertyName<TClass, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> property)
        {
            MemberExpression member = property.Body as MemberExpression;
            var info = member.Member as PropertyInfo;
            return info.Name;
        }
```